# Unable to connect to mysql host from flask app inside docker compose

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile, flask-sqlalchemy

I know this might be tagged a duplicate question but i have basically tried everything that i got on the internet.

I have designed a simple REST API with mysql backend. To run the app i am trying to use docker compose to bring both of them up but my when i bring my container up it tries to run db.create_all from inside a file but it says that it is unable to connect. Below are my relevant files :

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

## make a local directory
RUN mkdir /flask_rest_service

WORKDIR /flask_rest_service

ADD . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD python code/sqlinit.py && python code/app.py
```

sqlinit.py:

```
from models.user_model import UserModel
from app import app, db


def main():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        admin = UserModel(username='admin', password='admin', email='subhayan.here@gmail.com')
        admin.save_to_db()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Docker compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    container_name: web-service
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: restapi
```

settings.py file :

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)
DEBUG = True
PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root:rootpass@db/restapi'
JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = timedelta(seconds=60)
JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES = timedelta(seconds=300)
JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED = True
JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS = ['access', 'refresh']
```

From what i can see is that sqlinit.py seems to be the issue. But i don't know how to solve it. When my app starts up there has to be an admin user in the database hence i have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For your service and db composition file, I would also expose the mysql port as well, so your python app can access the standard mysql container with the default 3306 TCP port.

So your `compose.yml` would look like:

```
version: '2'
services:

  ...

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: restapi
```

Hope this helps!